# IPv6-only Windows Server remote acess from IPv4-only client

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, ipv6, ipv4

I have one Windows Server in a network where my ISP give me a public IPv6 and an CGNAT IPv4, because of that, it can not be accessible from an IPv4-only client. Is there any way i can make this server accessible by port 3389 to IPv4-only clients without messing with the client-side, only with server-side configurations?

Comment: What is your client specifically?

Comment: One windows 7 and one android phone, but they don't have ipv6 access

Comment: You will need to get IPv6 access from your other ISP and your mobile provider.

Comment: No way with a NAT or something like that? I don't wanna mess with the client-side ISP or systems